# mysql DISTINCT GROUP QUERY How do i list the groups

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database with messages and i am trying to display the users and the number of messages the user has sent on a webpage, However i can only manage to get the number of users out of the query, But after heavy investigation i found that my query is correct but the way i am outputting is incorrect, however i have no idea how i am to display the username and the amount of messages at the same time..

Could anybody help me understand how to output the results correctly like this..

```
 messages
```

user1 (3)  user2 (6)

here is my query and output at present.

i really do appreciate any help from you guys as this has been wracking my brain all day.

Thanks.

```
<div id='containercontact' class='containercontact'>


<?php

    include_once('contactselect.php');
?>


</div>


-----contactselect.php----(variables set by another page with an ajax send)

if (isset($_GET['listID'])){$listID=$_GET['listID'];}

if (isset($_GET['itemaccountname'])){$itemaccountname=$_GET['itemaccountname'];}

if (isset($_GET['useraccountname'])){$useraccountname=$_GET['useraccountname'];}

if (isset($_GET['selecteduser'])){$selecteduser=$_GET['selecteduser'];} else {$selecteduser="nil";}



                if ($useraccountname===$itemaccountname) {

                echo"


<div class='userbox'>
<header class='ubheader'>Messages From</header>
<section class='ubmain'>
";


    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=messages", 'root', ''); // 1. set database with this instead of conect - or change conect to this

    $query="SELECT DISTINCT messageaccountname,count(*) FROM `messagedatabase` WHERE `listID`='$listID' GROUP BY messageaccountname";

    $stat=$db->prepare($query);

    $stat->execute();
        $Ccount = $stat->rowCount();
        $contactcount=$Ccount;

        if ($contactcount <1) {
        echo"<div id='namecon' class='ubnames' >NO MESSAGES YET</div>"; 
        }
        else {

                    while($row = $stat->fetch()){
                         $messageaccountname=$row['messageaccountname'];


                            if ($messageaccountname != $useraccountname){
                                        echo"<div id='namecon' class='ubnames' onclick='selectmessage(\"{$messageaccountname}\")'>{$messageaccountname}</div>"; 
                            }
                    }


        }
echo "
</section>

</div>
";              


            } 

?>

<script>

function selectmessage(selectauser){

    var selected=selectauser;
    var varLISTID = document.getElementById('datacatch').getAttribute("data-variable-LISTID");
    var varUSERACCOUNTNAME = document.getElementById('datacatch').getAttribute("data-variable-USERACCOUNTNAME");
    var varITEMACCOUNTNAME = document.getElementById('datacatch').getAttribute("data-variable-ITEMCCOUNTNAME");

    var mylink = "loadmessages.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser="+selected;
    $('#infobox1').load(mylink);


}


</script>
```

I THINK IV DONE IT

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=messages", 'root', ''); // 1. set database with this instead of conect - or change conect to this

    $query="SELECT DISTINCT messageaccountname,count(*) FROM `messagedatabase` WHERE `listID`='$listID' GROUP BY messageaccountname";

    $stat=$db->prepare($query);

    $stat->execute();
        $Ccount = $stat->rowCount();
        $contactcount=$Ccount;

        if ($contactcount <1) {
        echo"<div id='namecon' class='ubnames' >NO MESSAGES YET</div>"; 
        }
        else {

                    while($row = $stat->fetch()){

                        $messagenumber = $row['count(*)'];
                         $messageaccountname=$row['messageaccountname'];


                            if ($messageaccountname != $useraccountname){
                                        echo"<div id='namecon' class='ubnames' onclick='selectmessage(\"{$messageaccountname}\")'>{$messageaccountname}{$messagenumber}</div>"; 
                            }
                    }


        }
```

Comment: Where is `$useraccountname` set? Maybe the value matches so you never echo? You also are misusing prepared statements. You should parameterize the query... or maybe the issue is you don't know how to access the `count(*) ` in PHP? I'd use an alias in the SQL. Not really clear where your issue currently is though.

Comment: hang il update the code

Comment: So that works for you? You should change `WHERE \`listID\`='$listID'` to `WHERE \`listID\`=?` then pass `$listID` in an array in the execute. `$stat->execute(array($listID));`

Comment: ok, yeah iv been being a bit sloppy with the PDO but i inmtent to secure it all as soon as i have a working platform... But im slowly getting into the habit of using ? ..

Comment: Tip: Any time you find yourself with both `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in the same (level of) query, you can fairly confident that you're doing something wrong.